# Upload Video and Audio to laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I've searched around on how to upload video and audio but I am stacking please help on this, here is code.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
     'name' =>  'required',
     'file' => 'required|mimes:mpeg,3gp,ogg,mp4,webm,3gp,mov,flv,avi,wmv,ts|nullable|max:100040'
    ]);


    if($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
      $filenameWithExt = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
      $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
      $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
      $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/file',$fileNameToStore);
    }
    else
    {
        $fileNameToStore = 'No Video selected please! check and try again.';
    }

    $vids = new Video;
    $vids->name = $request->input('name');
    $vids->file = $request->input('file');
   // $vids->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $vids->file = $fileNameToStore;
    $vids->save();

    return redirect('/videos')->with('success','Video Upload');
}
```

Comment: here is blade<form action="{{ action('VideosController@store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" file="true">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="name" placeholder="title"></textarea>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
     <input type="file" name="file" class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">
  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

Comment: what error is you're having exaclty?

Comment: it does upload video

Comment: it is does not upload video to database

Comment: *it is does not upload video to database* - are you going to store video as a binary data?

Comment: what i actually noticed is that you used `PATHINFO_FILENAME` without any initialization, so if necessary remove `PATHINFO_FILENAME` or initialize it before using it

Comment: yes-Tarasovych 2 hours ago

Comment: I remove but problem still not solved abokor hassa